# Base64 Encoder not encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons

So I have a program that is *supposed* to encode UTF-8 Base64, but is not. My Encoder code is as follows:

```
public class Encoder {
    public static void Encode() throws IOException{
          byte[] bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(readFile("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Diamond.png", StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
          String binary = new String(bytes);
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.txt");
          out.println(binary);
          out.close();
          System.out.println("Your File has been saved at C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.txt");
    }
    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
              throws IOException 
            {
              byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
              return new String(encoded, encoding);
            }
}
```

And when I decode it with this website (That has UTF-8 Functionality): http://www.base64decode.org/ I get:
Input (My code made this):

```
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
```

Expected output from website:

```
‰PNG


IHDR         óÿa   tEXtAuthor minecraftinfo.comßf'K   ²IDAT8Ëcøÿÿ?%Á@<æÿ‘1º<^@Ðº!8
€i^ôí9_üõù¿Áí½(†`5 ¦¤¦¼Þ^c¢
€iÃ ]a ºæž/P°ÂÔFWà5 d#.`®Ài H³ÎÙX
®Îc¼À¤ƒa«°@iÙÓ Ã01œa 3 äG\Àl'˜Œît¢“26Œ7)SœÉÅ aÍ^L‹    IEND®B`‚
```

Actual output From website:

```
�PNG


IHDR��atEXtAuthorminecraftinfo.com�f'K�IDAT8�c���?%�@<���1�<^@��!8
�i^��9_�����(�`5�����^c�
�i� �]�a��/�P���FW�5d#.`��iH��ٍX
���c����a��@i���01�a3�G\�l'������t��26�7)S���a�^L�IEND�B`�
```

However, when I encode the same exact thing using this site and not my code, It DOES have UTF-8 Formatting and decodes correctly. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Base64.encodeBase64` take `byte[]` as input. You should pass result of `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))` to `Base64.encodeBase64` directly.