# Decoding Base64 string with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, base64, eml

I am trying to decode an attachment that is being passed with the content for an EML file. The base64 encoded string that is passed for the attachment looks different than what I get if I encode the same file. It has a lot of the 77+9 fillers scattered throughout the string. When I try to decode the attachment I am getting corrupted files with a lot of the question mark symbols which makes me feel like I am missing some encoding somewhere. I have seen other questions with similar issues going the other direction ([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489131/base64-encoder-not-encoding-utf-8)) but I am having trouble reverse engineering those to get a solution. I have tried all sorts of variations between Base64 and UTF-8 encoding/decoding to try to get the expected result with no luck.

To avoid posting too much content on the question initially, I will truncate the value that is being passed, but wanted to show an example of what I am getting in the body:

> 77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAA77+9AAAA77+9CAYAAADvv71H77+9UwAA
> Ae+/vWlDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAKO+/vX3vv709SO+/vUAY77+937ZK77+9
> 77+9OO+/vUHvv70hQ3Xvv70gKu+/vVHvv71Q77+9Cu+/vVZo77+977+977+9
> 77+9P2jSkO+/ve+/vTgK77+9BQd/Fu+/vQ4uzro677+9Cu+/ve+/vQ/vv73v
> v73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv71dUmgR77+9He+/vT3vv73vv73vv70vd++/
> vQHvv71m77+977+9Zu+/vQTvv71q77+977+9SSXvv71cflUI77+9Iu+/vX5E
> aCYkZu+/vXPvv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv713ce+/ve+/vV3v
> v73vv70oBe+/vQE+77+9eO+/ve+/vUXvv71BPO+/vWnvv73vv73vv73vv73v
> v70sKe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQZd77+977+977+977+977+9b++/vUsO77+9eWbv
> v73vv71m5omj77+9Qu+/ve+/ve+/vS5mZUMl77+9Ju+/vSnvv71G77+977+9
> 77+977+9Cu+/vS3vv71q77+977+977+977+977+9LwwX77+977+9Ze+/ve+/
> vRpBCu+/vVjvv70IATLqqKAKC3Hvv701Ukxk77+9PO+/ve+/vR9277+9Iu+/
> vWRyVe+/vcix77+9GlRI77+9H++/vQ9+77+977+9LE5N77+9Se+/vSTvv73v ...

A very simple example of one of the numerous things I have tried:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(part.Content.Stream))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

// content is now set to the string example provided above

var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
attachment.Data = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

As requested, this is a very small sample of the raw EML with a small PNG coming through

```
 Received: by mx0120p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id NKNFIDnNGd Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:05:03 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from us-smtp-delivery-104.mimecast.com (unknown [170.10.133.104]) by mx0120p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id ED2B8960D02 for <131193@sample.com>; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:05:02 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sample.com; s=mimecast20190423; t=1628867102; h=from:from:reply-to:subject:subject:date:date:message-id:message-id: to:to:cc:cc:mime-version:mime-version:content-type:content-type: references:references; bh=pikFkoCNH4HZhtlP8qDB+spizIcC26WnsgTPv8eyj34=; b=XbgtbJLm/QWoaJL6zo4LvgzUkraT+ornC+Imdc6+g8roz1qnmP2oEz6FcKuH7mRSHlX9ZQ NYoHEofxM4WbTdqn3oyMGJQx7d8OqojQxiiIickiYQb84jn4eOqkCuimJ7XWHRv80D9qdN nzt3re4VcMaaBID034s6z8vCQqD1i40=
Received: from mail.sample.com (mail10.sample.com [66.35.88.157]) (Using TLS) by relay.mimecast.com with ESMTP id us-mta-42-BJ6QrSP1OP2M1noI0aT6FQ-7; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 11:05:00 -0400
X-MC-Unique: BJ6QrSP1OP2M1noI0aT6FQ-7
Received: from NAM12-MW2-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (104.47.66.48) by mail.sample.com (10.3.5.102) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.3.498.0; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 11:05:05 -0400
Received: from DM6PR18CA0033.namprd18.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:5:15b::46) by MN2PR10MB3232.namprd10.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:126::13) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4415.13; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:50 +0000
Received: from DM6NAM10FT068.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com (2603:10b6:5:15b:cafe::f8) by DM6PR18CA0033.outlook.office365.com (2603:10b6:5:15b::46) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4415.16 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:50 +0000
X-MS-Exchange-Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 65.52.215.36) smtp.mailfrom=sample.com; gmail.com; dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;gmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none header.from=sample.com
Received: from us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com (65.52.215.36) by DM6NAM10FT068.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.152.136) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4415.16 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:50 +0000
Received: from NAM11-CO1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (104.47.56.177) by us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com with CodeTwo SMTP Server (TLS12) via SMTP; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:49 +0000
Received: from MN2PR10MB3520.namprd10.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:111::21) by BLAPR10MB5026.namprd10.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:322::15) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4415.13; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:46 +0000
Received: from MN2PR10MB3520.namprd10.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::5d6d:dda9:61ba:30ae]) by MN2PR10MB3520.namprd10.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::5d6d:dda9:61ba:30ae%3]) with mapi id 15.20.4415.019; Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:46 +0000
From: Some User <user@sample.com>
To: "test@gmail.com" <test@@gmail.com>
CC: "131193@sample.com" <131193@sample>
Subject: Test PNG
Thread-Topic: Test PNG
Thread-Index: AQHXkFSN7A8O5wYnLEKMPRc8jH/uig==
Date: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:46 +0000
Message-ID: <B5C52C9A-0A1F-4F9F-B3E7-169321E931C5@sample.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
user-agent: Microsoft-MacOutlook/16.50.21061301
Authentication-Results-Original: gmail.com; dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;gmail.com; dmarc=none action=none header.from=sample.com
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: fb6df58d-7f14-472c-6565-08d95e6bb2e8
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: BLAPR10MB5026:|MN2PR10MB3232:
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS: <MN2PR10MB3232C53C88A8D0A81E0C103FD4FA9@MN2PR10MB3232.namprd10.prod.outlook.com>
x-ms-oob-tlc-oobclassifiers: OLM:1728;OLM:4502
X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck: 1
X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-Relay: 0
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Untrusted: BCL:0
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info-Original: 82YtXaJNBlwxS+o4Zym4QvMeI6i3Meo/vj/WlN2XpOuQSsmq/t51Uaq/Nt92VnTSV0hossyUhscua3Xd85MuY771UA1UuIrcn+5VvltIYHQ6FsqYZG9s1bZis/fb+wGQ9z3kWUByOdqZZTTq/YIzGSjn4SjTAEeL8Wf9PI8BY0MBU9BD3dIYl10ux4JU2YAwjfI/sdksUSVT/LPbZQPCG+XSNFxyXGbKN3tKFfqK1cQc4G3MvpsmBdVyHSMu/1uLx0M6KrY8myF8mm8NFc4j1hpTENMrb5EJIK2mUXJYA+t4Bku+zwh1oEeuSI8GuJgfzDnxFlcTcZVXoshkiFPuJ36SsmXBn0vMR1Kl4LitUb4Ku0zVZvPinjo0WOaUZPdk26+puEfKnxwm9FZ2JM8yWAEAnLEcDTBLaP5l/XlaEpMeJzizNOZLVEP6aCqev98Z10AGKpC5NqRpudRYjeOciBMfppARZu4RHEw9LLpi+1A=
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted: CIP:255.255.255.255;CTRY:;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:MN2PR10MB3520.namprd10.prod.outlook.com;PTR:;CAT:NONE;SFS:(4636009)(39860400002)(376002)(366004)(346002)(396003)(136003)(8676002)(186003)(6506007)(7116003)(99936003)(38070700005)(66616009)(66556008)(66476007)(64756008)(66946007)(66446008)(316002)(33656002)(6512007)(3480700007)(4326008)(2616005)(6916009)(122000001)(2906002)(38100700002)(5660300002)(86362001)(8936002)(6486002)(73894004)(91956017)(71200400001)(4270600006)(478600001)(36756003)(76116006)(45980500001);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101
x-ms-exchange-antispam-messagedata-chunkcount: 1
x-ms-exchange-antispam-messagedata-0: =?utf-8?B?aXAxSzl4UldmZzBYNzczMW1qSmt6OEpzcncvc3FabWd2azg4VHJ5SWtzQzZ3?= =?utf-8?B?VWR5bFhQQUVMYnBiSmtDeVVZdlgvZTU0VmxDUG1iSXBlbFNOaWZESWx2WU1m?= =?utf-8?B?cTZVcUd5U3BLQUgxeUxQclZvbFFiZkNUM2thejRoSURpNVFPUXc5SnpnYVQ4?= =?utf-8?B?NFp3RHdFL1dOZVZjU1FEeVJMVlFZSUE1bnIwUHUwS1VqUmVCVU9Ha0Q0RCtz?= =?utf-8?B?bG5Na1lRZDdZSkZ2M3c2c1NNZ3QzMUVWR0tVMnpod3JrQ2NKMUwzeW81ckYy?= =?utf-8?B?TG5hdXVIYWJsN0NZNXNCOFlBOGtPeVQ1d2lSSktsdDNPTkJNdE1xblFKMEtl?= =?utf-8?B?YUpaWU85eGZIeldLeUJCUHdBUFo4bEkyYnNsemRXR0VkNjNDWHpMbzRrazlP?= =?utf-8?B?bnlCYkNFS3lIRmR2My82R2ZDMFVtbkZmWEZYdTNUdEJlcWJSL21wdTRaSXR5?= =?utf-8?B?M24rbU5GeVRGVGNnU3FzSDBIUGRVd1BIK05DTnJlT2lDbklhN3NpZnBkeUgx?= =?utf-8?B?a0dYM05kMHl0anN1YWRUcmREMG5xdDJRU2d5UmxVNENBY0pmY1pwOVQzSFFq?= =?utf-8?B?cWxqK0lJaFRyeDR1VlNBREl5TUJpeTZFRnc4Qk9zMTc0ckUvS25sb0g0amVu?= =?utf-8?B?eFFhWm5PdEpPbW5OcFd3NXUwQUZyRHFFUXVhQVBVVTRtVTRGTnRCTWQ0NUUv?= =?utf-8?B?RGlUQldySmswQytnQ3FZYjlJZFNZVFRCTFFKS1JRZXFUSXNpM1ZmWEIrNG56?= =?utf-8?B?cE5KWUFWUFQ2U09rcHBSQ0R4QncyekZSZ3Zzbng1NURGZXJxRG9JOTdBc3Q0?= =?utf-8?B?cVdMTHpXVmVBTnhBMEMwMVlUazRWeHBSc21VQlJ3cGlaQ1pFUjBwRGZTdW5Q?= =?utf-8?B?TXo0bUJhQmV0alg3NjZrUkxRSmM3V3BSY001dzY2YTVHUktpMUVRVStWTG51?= =?utf-8?B?OS9EeTBVZFhzbUhaWDBsVEhxU0RxcEt0YkYwT1VkKy9kejBPWjhqdWc5YjNG?= =?utf-8?B?dUszQ3QwZ1dmK0dxSzhkZXBUdDMvS08vZk1CMkJhNFE0UWlNaG5lYVh5NWIv?= =?utf-8?B?cWxIbzhlR2NTWmhRWDNKZGJyQmZJL1BxWDdHd25vMmFwc09zT0cwdlc4OGdm?= =?utf-8?B?WDFVUUxQaFNSQVpFUVhELytISjBueVNGK01saENWZTg4aHZjSUdVTmV6QzhH?= =?utf-8?B?UWZmSFFZcXVjQUtOMnpoeVVXQmFnZ1BmcDlGYXJuWU15aUhsUzhqdlFxQnlh?= =?utf-8?B?amtFVTBPbktYN2diOU8ybW1VK1lCTVZ0K2VBemRqUGo2RWZkMStSajMwU2Vk?= =?utf-8?B?c0NLOWcrLzJGS0c2blBhK0VCeWk0Qk9Mb0M2NDRjNktDcXRRdFhvbVVqMUkz?= =?utf-8?B?dWExaEcwZHJLQ2xJaXNSSnNoUldaUHhweDZDU3Z3UnYwQ3ZyU0NXSFRNS2o1?= =?utf-8?B?MXM2bmhWZHhJR21RR3o0Y3NMRHphUkJjbWtmNiszQU9XblVwZ0JXeGtybFNs?= =?utf-8?B?N0YyT3BTcnR5b3paVmFhT2RWSmpnZExBdGNlanpaV0R5VXdVTStQWXhucW1r?= =?utf-8?B?ZC9QWHdZVUFFUHJhQXErbmEwbmJQTVZ5T01XL0grS1FpMmlaZ1k1aUhYQ3Rp?= =?utf-8?B?TGR2YkU4b0pYNGJUOTRISEdQL05IRXIxbXgxc0JBRk1GSGxOSXpZUHpYMXFZ?= =?utf-8?B?cmVjU1ZRMldBQTJSaWhwL1liNFpRRVJ3aXFWTSs2NlZaalFQR3g2UytiYTVC?= =?utf-8?B?Vlc1c3FpVi9td3JCTHRDY1hsTUhDRU1VRWVhSWo4TC9kY0kyL1NsdGxxOHMz?= =?utf-8?B?OEl1MVdXYThHck9EallienhPZkFrMGtRa0lodUNTTDAwM0crWXQ4RGJaRVZw?= =?utf-8?B?NU11SWYzNGhrcU1LdWsrcmdSajh3QTd4RzNrZ0RSVlp6cVE9PQ==?=
x-ms-exchange-transport-forked: True
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BLAPR10MB5026
X-CodeTwo-MessageID: a419b849-8d8e-410f-b466-a44cbcbd5b8c.20210813150449@us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com
X-CodeTwoProcessed: true
References: <728f62a7-8dc1-441e-9928-a71bb9efb6b4.a8ecc3b3-6542-4515-92cd-95d549654576.369a482b-6a97-4e0b-87f3-298c42ac6818@emailsignatures365.codetwo.com> <728f62a7-8dc1-441e-9928-a71bb9efb6b4.27a142a5-09c7-4c13-8322-0371aa0edf75.0080e9b6-43f5-4498-bf10-bf50ad09d4e9@emailsignatures365.codetwo.com>
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStripped: DM6NAM10FT068.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id-Prvs: de9ab81e-fd57-4256-d9b9-08d95e6bb095
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info: 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
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:65.52.215.36;CTRY:US;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com;PTR:us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com;CAT:NONE;SFS:(4636009)(376002)(346002)(136003)(39860400002)(396003)(36840700001)(46966006)(82310400003)(316002)(6916009)(86362001)(47076005)(36860700001)(33656002)(6486002)(99936003)(235185007)(2906002)(4326008)(5660300002)(8936002)(82740400003)(45080400002)(26005)(66616009)(2616005)(83380400001)(8676002)(336012)(166002)(3480700007)(186003)(7116003)(356005)(478600001)(33964004)(7596003)(70206006)(7636003)(70586007)(36756003)(6506007)(6512007);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 13 Aug 2021 15:04:50.5132 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: fb6df58d-7f14-472c-6565-08d95e6bb2e8
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 12a79007-c974-4bc6-841f-9314b73ea7b3
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalAttributedTenantConnectingIp: TenantId=12a79007-c974-4bc6-841f-9314b73ea7b3;Ip=[65.52.215.36];Helo=[us3-emailsignatures-cloud.codetwo.com]
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource: DM6NAM10FT068.eop-nam10.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: HybridOnPrem
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: MN2PR10MB3232
X-C2ProcessedOrg: 2e87726c-1af2-43dc-9aa2-7c64bc3068be
Authentication-Results: relay.mimecast.com; auth=pass smtp.auth=CUSA4A18 smtp.mailfrom=user@sample.com
X-Mimecast-Spam-Score: 0
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_004_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_"

--_004_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="_000_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_"

--_000_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[Omitted not needed]

--_000_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <25807D813F59D448B83FCDB5CF311BBA@namprd10.prod.outlook.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[Omitted not needed]

--_000_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_--

--_004_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_
Content-Type: image/png; name="tiny.png"
Content-Description: tiny.png
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tiny.png"; size=556;
        creation-date="Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:46 GMT";
        modification-date="Fri, 13 Aug 2021 15:04:46 GMT"
Content-ID: <12E33C5609C62F47AB355AF7E70F2A96@namprd10.prod.outlook.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--_004_B5C52C9A0A1F4F9FB3E7169321E931C5_--
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @Flydog57 which one of my numerous encoding/decoding attempts would you like to see that have failed to get the expected result? I can post my latest I guess

Comment: Don't you want `Convert.FromBase64String`?

Comment: @canton7 good callout, that was just from me clearing the wrong line out that was commented when I posted it here. Updated, and good eye

Comment: I'm confused. The first line says you're decoding an attachment, but your code clearly shows you *encoding* it, and setting the encoded data as an attachment?

Comment: @Llama it isn't a base64 string in that instance. As a note this isn't a solution I expected to work necessarily, it is just one of the many attempts I have tried. At this point I am grasping at straws because my expectations weren't working

Comment: That base64 is a PNG file, so you don't want to convert it to a string anyway. Especially not with UTF8 since that isn't designed for binary data.

Comment: The code you have now looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried to save the base64 data to a file and manually decode it in any online tool. to see that you received a correct file to troubleshoot the problem

Comment: @canton7  have updated my code provided to be the solution I expected to work. I was just posting the latest thing I was trying because after a day of trying all different types of things I feel like I am starting to lose my mind and am trying anything.

Comment: @Llama see above comment to canton

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @zgc7009 I'm still confused. Your latest code still assigns *to* the attachment, but your question still says you're reading *from* an attachment. Which is correct?

Comment: The file that is downloaded will not open, it is corrupted. I can post an example of what I am getting vs what I am expecting

Comment: @canton7 I am reading from an attachment (part.Content.Stream) into an attachment object (attachment.Data) that I am using for storing files and uploading the data to our server

Comment: The data I obtained from your base64 resembles a PNG file (in terms of its content) but it appears to be corrupted. How did you come to have the base64-encoded data? How was it generated?

Comment: So we're not seeing the entire picture. Are you sure the mis-translation isn't happening somewhere else?

Comment: [Hex view of your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzKLM.png) vs [Hex view of valid PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOe0A.png). It looks like your data was corrupted before it was converted to base64.

Comment: I see `part.Content.Stream` - is `part` a `MimePart` from MimeKit? If so, you can use `part.Content.DecodeTo()` to base64 decode it.

Comment: I've taken my valid PNG, interpreted it as a UTF8-encoded string, and then encoded that string back to bytes using UTF8, and it appears to produce the same corruption as your base64 data. [Hex view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmInR.png)

Comment: Note that Convert.FromBase64String() does not like line breaks or other "garbage" that can appear in base64 encoded MIME content, so you need to use a base64 decoder that is built to handle that (like MimeKit's).

Comment: The value I am getting is coming directly from the raw EML content. When I take the png and try to base64 encode it I get a different value than is provided to me in the EML. The EML is able view the attachment fine within the EML itself so there has to be a way to decode the individual attachments that are parsed from the EML, no?

Comment: Can you show how you're obtaining and parsing the raw EML content?

Comment: @Llama the raw content is provided via SendGrid, a Twilio integration that produces the content for us. It is interesting you are able to get the same corrupted data from your PNG

Comment: @jstedfast interesting. I looked through their documentation but must have missed that. Let me give that a go

Comment: Can you produce a tiny sample EML file (e.g. with a 2x2 pixel PNG) and include its content in your question?

Comment: 0xefbfbd appears a lot in the hex dump from @Llama That's the default replacement character. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm

Comment: @Llama Bingo, nice one. `EF BF BD` is the UTF-8 encoding of U+FFFD, the Unicode Replacement Character. Which makes sense, as the `89` (the first byte of the PNG magic value) isn't a valid UTF-8 byte at that point

Comment: So someone's certainly taken the raw bytes from a png file and interpreted them as UTF-8 characters at some point. People for some reason think it's OK to read binary data into a string, and it's really not

Comment: @Llama added a tiny sample with minor edits/omissions for security/clarity reasons

Comment: @canton7 that would make sense and would also mean that there isn't a real way for me to actually manage this data without it ending up corrupted. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: I can already tell that the base64 in your sample is likely a valid PNG file because it starts with "iv". And sure enough, I can open it in paint and it's a 2x2 white PNG. Does your code parse this sample correctly?

Comment: **If** the sample you showed is the UTF-8 decoding of `part.Content.Stream`, and if `part.Content.Stream` has nothing to do with your code (the first access you get to this thing is the first line of code in your question), then yes you might be stuck. Trying to load binary data as UTF-8 lost some of the information, and it can't be reconstructed

Comment: @Llama so interestingly enough this one does parse correctly for me. It is the first one that does. That is something. I have reached out to the vendor again to see if they can shed some more light on the situation. it almost makes it weirder that it would process some correctly and others would come through corrupted. Thank you very much for your insight on this one.

Comment: @canton7 I do not have control over the input data that is correct. I get what I get. I will reach out to the vendor now that I have some more information. Thank you as well for all of your help.

Comment: I hope you can find a solution :)